# Splitted Array being filled in for loop by function calculating values from a splitted array

Tags: python, arrays, function, for-loop, signal-processing

I got stuck at a for loop Problem.

I have a signal as an array and I split it up in multiple epochs.

```
times = np.arange(0, duration, 1 / sfreq)
nse1 = np.random.rand(times.size) * nse_amp
x =  amp * np.sin( 2 * np.pi * 200 * times            ) + nse1
x2 = np.array_split(x,epochs)
```

I do this a second time for a y-signal.
Let's say my signal x has the shape of (100) then my splitted array for 2 epochs should have the form of (2, 50).

Now I want to use a function in a for loop to calculate a value for each value of each segment of my split up array...Something like:

```
for i in range(0,epochs):
    Rxy[i], freqs_xy[i] = mlab.csd(x2[i], y2[i], NFFT=nfft, Fs=sfreq)
```

So I will get an array for Rxy like (2, 50)

Hope you get what I want to do.

Greetings,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build `Rxy` as an array, allocate space for the array first:

```
Rxy = np.empty_like(x2)
freqs_xy = np.empty_like(x2)
```

then you can fill in the rows of `Rxy` using the loop:

```
for i in range(2):
    Rxy[i], freqs_xy[i] = mlab.csd(x2[i], y2[i], NFFT=nfft, Fs=sfreq)
```

---

By the way, `np.array_split(x,epochs)` returns a *list* of arrays. That's not
the same as an array of shape `(2, 50)`. If you can guarantee that `epochs`
splits `x` into arrays of equal length, you could use

```
x2 = x.reshape(2, -1)
```

instead. Then `x2` would be an *array* of shape `(2, 50)`.  `reshape` is faster
than `array_split` since `reshape` only has to change an attribute while
`array_split` has to allocate and copy data into new arrays.  Moroever, it's
generally better to keep data in a big array rather than parts in a list of
arrays, since computation on the list generally requires Python loops which are
the bane of performance when using NumPy. Of course, sometimes Python loops
can't be avoided, as appears to be the case here when calling `mlab.csd`.